# What is the value of a user profile image?

Tags: user-profile, personalisation

Does a user profile need to show their image? Somewhere I came to  understand that this will give the user more of a feeling of personalization, but would it add any other value?

Answer (score 1):

**People scan before they read.** Profile photos are highly valuable where there is user interaction on a website - think of this one, where you can look at the various avatars and not even need to read their name to quickly understand who has posted an answer to a question.

Profile pictures can also help build a community, and promote gamification and participation. When you see a bunch of customizable alien avatars having a conversation on Reddit, you feel a connection with your fellow sub-Redditors.

If there isn't user interaction, though, there might not be much value in adding profile pictures. Profile pics can even be detrimental in some cases, too - think product reviews, where reviewers might use politically controversial, inappropriate, or hateful pictures while giving opinions on a product or brand. If you add profile pics, you're going to likely need to moderate them and have rules around usage.

It's worth weighing pros and cons. There are [good articles](https://uxdesign.cc/should-i-use-avatars-in-my-product-598735baaa54) about it.

Comment: But is it adding any value to the banking app?

Comment: Does the app fit any of the use cases mentioned in my answer?